# How to delete a line from a text file if the line contains a specific element C#

Tags: c#

- Text file line structure example: `element1,element2,element3`
- The number of `elements` is static i.e. There will only be 3 `elements` per line
- I will always be using the 2nd `element` of each line
- I want to delete the line from the text file if `element2` = `DeleteId`

Code that I have so far:

```
var categoryFile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Categories.txt");

var tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
var linesToKeep = System.IO.File.ReadLines(categoryFile).Where(l => l != Convert.ToString(DeleteId));

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(tempFile, linesToKeep);

System.IO.File.Delete(categoryFile);
System.IO.File.Move(tempFile, categoryFile);
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how I would have to modify the code above to be able to delete the row if it contains the `DeleteId`. Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: If it's always the second element and there's only ever three elements then you could do a simple contains or a regex for `,DeleteId,` i.e. with a leading and trailing comma. Otherwise you'll probably want to split the line by commas, or properly parse it using a CSV library, to extract the second field to test.

Comment: Can you share the simple example of file?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski The first bullet point is an example of a line in the file, do you mean of my actual file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this

```
var linesToKeep = System.IO.File.ReadLines(categoryFile).Where(l => l.Split(',')[1] != "DeleteId");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! your code works I'll accept it when the timer allows me to.